# Question on equivalence of definitions regarding convergence with respect to a measure

Tags: measure-theory

I have been asked a question about the convergence with respect to measures,and the definition they used was the following: $f_n$ converges to $f$ w.r.t. $\mu$ exactly when $\mu \{x \in X: f_n(x)$ does not converge to $f(x)$ $\}$ $= 0$. The definition I have however is $\mu \{x \in X: |f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq \epsilon\}$ $= 0$. Assuming these are equivalent, I tried to see how they are. I clearly am getting something wrong here, but I started this way: Remembering the definition of convergence of sequences: for every $\epsilon$ $>0$ there exists an $N_{\epsilon}$ $\in \mathbb{N}$ with $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$ for all $n \geq N_{\epsilon}$. This should then mean that "non convergence" means: There exists an $\epsilon > 0 $ with $|a_n-a| \geq \epsilon$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This then leads to (regarding the first definition) $\mu \{x \in X: |f_n(x)-f(x)| \geq \epsilon$ for one $\epsilon >0$ for all $n \in \mathbb {N}$}$= 0$. This should be the same as saying there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ with $\mu (\cap$ over all $n\in \mathbb{N}\{x \in X: |f_n(x)-f(x)| \geq \epsilon$}$)= 0$. If I knew that $\mu$ would be finite for all of those sets and the sequence of the sets is decreasing, I could simply rewrite this with the limit and almost reach the form of the 2nd definition, the difference being that I wrote "there exists one(!) epsilon, not for all epsilon (...). Did I do something wrong, or is the other defintion just more strict in a way? Furthermore, if I am correct, in order to write it in the form I mentioned, why would $\mu$ be finite for all the sets and why would the series of the sets be decreasing in general? I appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The first one is called almost everywhere convergence and the second one is called convergence in measure. They are not equivalent even if $\mu$ is a finite measure.

Arrange the intervals $[\frac {i-1} {2^{n}}, \frac i {2^{n}})$ in sequence. On $[0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure this gives an example of sequence which converges in measure but not almost surely.

Comment: I see, thank you very much!